# Jquery Alternating Rows with visability

Tags: jquery

Can Jquery zebra stripe a table where some rows are being set to 'display:none' and still have the visable rows alternate in color, without two rows having the same color next to each other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is possible with the [:visible](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/visible) and the [:odd](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/odd) (or the [:even](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/even)) selectors:

```
$('table').find('tr:visible:odd').addClass('odd');
```

Then you can do:

```
table tr td {
    background-color: #fff;
}

table tr.odd td {
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
}
```

Comment: How about $('tr:visible:odd').addClass('odd')?